# Structure of JSON array

Tags: php, json

I am writing form data into a JSON file using PHP. I am getting it in the form

```
[ 
    {
        "arrayname" : { "name":"abc","marks":"100"}
    },
    {
        "arrayname" : { "name":"def","marks":"100"}
    }
]
```

But I want it as

```
{
    "arrayname": [
        { "name":"abc","marks":"100"},
        { "name":"def","marks":"100"}
    ]
}
```

I am using the following PHP code

```
$formdata["arrayname"] = 
array
(

    'name'=> $_POST['name'],
    'marks' => $_POST['marks']
);
$arr_data = array();        // to store all form data
... // stuffs to append data and json_encode
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Are you asking about the formatting or the structure of the data?

Comment: structure. :) my mistake

Answer (score 0):

```
$formdata = array("arrayname" => array());

// Loop to add name/marks
    $formdata["arrayname"][] = array("name" => $name, "marks" => $marks);
```

Answer (score 0):

the first one is (in php);

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'arrayname' => array(
            'name' => 'abc',
            'marks' => '100'
        )
    ),
    array(
        'arrayname' => array(
            'name' => 'abc',
            'marks' => '100'
        )
    )
);
```

while the second one would be:

```
$array = array(
    'arrayname' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'abc',
            'marks' => '100'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'abc',
            'marks' => '100'
        )
    )
);
```

answers itself, so just figure out where you go wrong.

Comment: When next time I will add data will it be in structure i mentioned?

Comment: This isn't really an answer.

Comment: Well, it shows him where he went wrong. Since he, obviously, doesn't have the basic skills to transform his array to that format, he should read up on that first OR update the post to a format that i can actually correct it for him.